# KendoUI Grid ColumnMenu Undefined Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Wrapper for KendoUI in my project.

I saw Grid ColumnMenu and I want to use it and everything works but the menu lists 3 undefined columns.

My grid has 3 columns without model binding and with an empty title but I set this

```
.IncludeInMenu(false)
```

Nothing changes, so I've tried to comment those columns but nothing changes again.

EDIT:

The Grid Code, I cleaned it for readability.

```
Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("Grid")
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("", "").Data("")).Model(model => model.Id(m => m.ID)).PageSize(50).Events(events => events.RequestStart("")))
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Template(o => "").ClientTemplate("").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "white-space: nowrap;" }).Width(100).IncludeInMenu(false);

    columns.Template(o => "").Width(36).HeaderTemplate(h => "").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).ClientTemplate("").IncludeInMenu(false);

    columns.Template(o => "").Width(36).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" }).HeaderTemplate("").ClientTemplate("").IncludeInMenu(false);

    Html.OrderedColumns(columns);
})
.Selectable()
.Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(true).Height(300))
.Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
.Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
.ColumnMenu()
.Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true).SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn).AllowUnsort(true))
.Pageable(pageable => pageable.Enabled(true).Messages(t => t.Display("{0:d0} - {1:d0} of {2:d0} items")))
.Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(false))
.Events(e => e.DataBound("").ColumnResize("").ColumnHide("").ColumnShow("").ColumnReorder(""))
```

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: @corrego now there's the grid code

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplis. Hide the columns? You can try .Hidden()

Comment: I want to hide the columns from the dropdown menu. It shows 3 undefined columns.

Comment: The way you're doing it now does not specify which column you're referring to. Try `columns.Bound(model => model.[column you want to hide]).IncludeInMenu(false);`

Comment: Those 3 columns with template has no property to bind and must not be shown. Html.OrderedColumns() contains the bounded columns with reordering from DB data.

Comment: from the documentation: " By default all columns are included. The column also need to have a Title set in order to be included in the menu." Try setting the title to null or to an empty string.

Comment: I tried that but nothing changes, I've posted on their forum but they haven't answered yet.